# How to tell Cmake about Qt installation dir without changing PATH?

Tags: qt, cmake, qmake

In my `CMakeLists.txt`, I have a call like below

```
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Gui)
```

But for above to work, Qt needs to be set in the `PATH` like below.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64/bin
```

Having Qt in `PATH` of course works but I don't want to change `PATH` for every machine that my source code builds in. Is there way to tell Cmake about my Qt Installation Folder without changing `PATH` on the machine and without changing `CMakeLists.txt` of my project?

I have tried the following:

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64/bin
export CMAKE_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64/bin
export CMAKE_APPBUNDLE_PATH=/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64/bin
```

But above didn't help.

**Environment:**.
macOS Catalina
Cmake version 3.18.2
Qt 5.12.5

Comment: You should provide the root directory of your Qt installation to CMake, not the bin folder. Add CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH as parameter to your cmake call, e.g. `cmake -B <builddir> -S <sourcedir> -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...` didn't work is that you passed the `bin` subdirectory instead of the installation prefix, as @vre already pointed out in the comments.

Alternatively, you can use `-DQt5_ROOT=/Path/To/QtInstallationFolder/5.12.5/clang_64`. I personally prefer to use these kind of package specific variables because in CI build scripts you can easily put them on separate lines which then don't become too long.

Comment: "The reason `export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=...` doesn't work is that CMake expects this to be a CMake (Cache-)variable, not a environment variable" - Actually, CMake checks both variables, **CMake** one and **environment** one. See e.g. search procedure for [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Oh, I didn't know that. Thanks, I've updated the answer.